# How to find the similar column names from a database table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, information-schema

How do i find similar column names from a database table?

for e.g.

a database table

```
1_1  1_2  1_3  5_6  67
    |    |    |    |   
    |    |    |    |
```

So, 1_1, 1_2, 1_3, 5_6 and 67 are the column names of a database table. And i would like to retrieve only the column names starts with 1 (1_1, 1_2 and 1_3). i tried the sql query but it dint work..

**SELECT 1 LIKE '%1%' FROM sheet1;**

It shows something of this short

```
1 LIKE '%1%'
         1
         1
```

Comment: If you want to select columns, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? The table design most likely has optimization potential

Comment: i would like to retrieve all the column values based on the similar column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name FROM db_name
LIKE '1%'
```

To get the contents of the respective column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7eefe/1)

Comment: Thankyou @rkp... but how should i list the contents of the respective column?

Answer (score 0):

this may be useful to you

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='table' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database_name'
```

information_schema is database containing meta data about all databases so when ever you want this kind of data you simply fire query on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) INTO @s 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME LIKE '1%';

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @s, ' FROM tableName');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```